# Django 2.2 make migrations fails with cryptic (AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'ancestors') message while 2.1 succeeds

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-2.2

Have the following problem and I do not know how to tackle it:

While trying to `python manage.py makemigrations` on Django 2.2.10 even without anything new, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/migrate_sql/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 119, in handle
    migration_name=self.migration_name,
  File "/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 43, in changes
    changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
  File "/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 186, in _detect_changes
    self.generate_altered_fields()
  File "/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/migrate_sql/autodetector.py", line 255, in generate_altered_fields
    self.generate_sql_changes()
  File "/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/migrate_sql/autodetector.py", line 229, in generate_sql_changes
    keys = self.assemble_changes(new_keys, changed_keys, self.to_sql_graph)
  File "/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/migrate_sql/autodetector.py", line 95, in assemble_changes
    ancs = node.ancestors()[:-1]
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'ancestors'
```

The only way I could fix this was to revert back to Django 2.1.10 then create from then the models I needed and then install again. Then `python manage.py migrate` runs - on Django 2.2.10 without a problem.

Because of the message, I have no indication on what has gone wrong or why. Could it be one of the installed applications that are model related? Any idea how I should root-cause it?

Answer (score 0):

Issue with https://github.com/klichukb/django-migrate-sql which was one dependency.
Removing it made everything OK.